# Embedded Desmos Graphs

Tags: feature-request

As of late I have been using Desmos for a variety of demonstrations. Some of these demonstrations are humbly interactive. It seems to me it could be a nice feature to be able to embed the graph at the link into the answer (as opposed to including a link to desmos).

As far as I understand something like this is possible, at least in html, although I am ignorant as to whether or not it would be possible with Mathjax (or whatever system is the bottleneck as far as math stackexchange is concerned).

Here are some examples of answers of mine where I used Desmos. I hope these examples will demonstrate the potential benefit of being able to have the interactive graph embedded in the answer:

- [Is $\operatorname{Homeo}([0,1])$ Weil-Complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152666/169085)
- [How to obtain all solutions of separable differential equation where the existence and uniqueness theorem does not apply?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4515772/169085)
- [Discussion about necessity of compactness in Theorem 7.13 of Rudin's PMA](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4527091/169085)
- [If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then the zoom converges to the straight line through the origin with slope $f'(x_0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4573879/169085)
- [Equilibrium point of a function and its basin of attraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4604651/169085)
- [Line on torus as inspiration for finding counter example of homeomorphism theorem for topological group actions on topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618396/169085)

Just as I am writing this question, one potential negative effect of this implementation could be that the answers could possibly become too dependent on Desmos (e.g. imagine just an embedded Desmos graph as an answer), which is probably not preferable. I try to write my answers in which I use Desmos in such a way that even if the Desmos link goes dead the answer is still useful (or not less useful, at least) (of course link sharing (especially without writing the author and title explicitly and merely writing "this paper" or the link itself) suffers from a similar issue). You'll see in the examples above that at times I was less successful at doing this. I am also trying to figure out the Desmos sharing etiquette along the way of course (which I realized I am doing as I am writing this question).

Comment: I will say that the thought of something like this has occurred to me.  I suspect it would be at least as burdensome as embedding (for example) Youtube videos in posts.  Although visual illustrations can be helpful, I think a better balance between Math.SE content and Desmos content can be struck by using links rather than embeddings.

Comment: It would be nice, but I'm guessing it'll be a long time before embedding is an option. In the meantime, if you're willing to spend the extra effort, I think an embedded screenshot (at "typical" parameter values) along with the link would be great.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thanks, that's a good idea.